# Child-runs-first semantics in old linux kernels

Tags: process, linux-kernel, kernel, exec, copy-on-write

I was reading Linux Kernel development and trying to understand process address space semantics in case of fork(). While I'm reading in context of Kernel v2.6, and in newer versions, any of child or parent may run first, I am confused with following:

```
Back in do_fork(), if copy_process() returns successfully, the new child is woken up
and run. Deliberately, the kernel runs the child process first. In the common case of the
child simply calling exec() immediately, this eliminates any copy-on-write overhead
```

Based on my understanding of COW, if an exec () is used, COW will always happen, whether child or parent process runs first. Can someone explain how is COW eliminated in case of child running first? Does 'overhead' refer to an extra overhead that comes with COW instead of 'always copy' semantics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fork()` creates a copy of the parent's memory address space where all memory pages are initially shared between the parent and the child. All pages are markes as read-only, and on the first write to such a page, the page is copied so that parent and child have their own. (This is what COW is about.)

`exec()` throws away the entire current address space and creates a new one for the new program.

- If the child executes first and calls `exec()`, the none of the shared pages needs to be unshared.
- If the parent executes first and modifies some data, then these pages are unshared. If the child then starts executing and calls `exec()`, the copied pages will be thrown away, i.e., the unsharing was not actually necessary.

Comment: 1. this sounds as if in case1, child is able to use copied address space, while in case 2, it throws away the address space, and creates a new one. why? 2.  Which are these shared pages which remain shared even on encountering exec()?

Comment: 1. `exec()` runs an entirely new program; the effect is to terminate the current program. Throwing away all memory is a side effect of that. 2. Directly after `fork()`, all pages are shared.